# HTML 'behind' Javascript therefore preventing any text being seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have been playing around with [this](https://github.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/) Javascript but I can never get the HTML to be visible on the page. Here is my HTML code and once I open the page I do not see anything except for the canvas particle network.

```html
<html id="particle-canvas">

<head>
<title></title>
<!-- Main CSS Stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<!-- Stylesheet for the icons from Font Awesome-->
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="content"> text </div>
 <h1> Test </h1>
 <!-- javascript-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="CPN/particle-network.min.js">        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
  var options = {
   particleColor: '#116466',
   background: '#2C3531',
   interactive: false,
   speed: 'medium',
   density: 'high'
  };
 </script>
 <script> var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I open the page, I do not see **text** or **Test**. What am I doing wrong? If needed, the JavaScript that is running can be found [here](https://github.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/).

Comment: Works in snippet.

Comment: Yes, as the javascript is not in snippet. It links to a few different .js files and I was unsure how to place them all within snippet. You can find the exact files I am using [here](https://github.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your selector is applied to the `html` element itself, which means your whole page.

```
<html id="particle-canvas">
```

You need to remove `id="particle-canvas"` attribute from the `html` tag and apply it to a child element in the page.

Ex:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!-- Main CSS Stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <!-- Stylesheet for the icons from Font Awesome-->
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content"> text </div>
        <h1> Test </h1>
        <div id="particle-canvas" style="height:300px">

            <!-- javascript-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="particle-network.min.js">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
                var options = {
                    particleColor: '#116466',
                    background: '#2C3531',
                    interactive: false,
                    speed: 'medium',
                    density: 'high'
                };
            </script>
            <script>
                var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have tested that but now I do not see any of the javascript, only `<h1>` actually.  `<div class="content"> text </div>` is not visible.

Comment: Did you copy paste the code I have put here? make sure you change the JS file path to match yours. I have changed it.

Comment: I am not sure if [this](https://github.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/issues/6) issue opened in github is why I cannot see anything. I know the text is there as I can click F12 and highlight where the text is. Does that issue mean my background needs to be set at a lower opacity? How do I apply opacity to the 'background' option?

Comment: Not really, I didn't see any issue here other than that you had added the ID attribute to the html tag, which means it will cover the whole page anyway. Just try the code I have put in my answer (and make sure to have the right path to the javascript file)

Comment: Ah, yes that was it. I linked to my .js and I can see the `<h1>` but `<div class="content"> text </div>` is not visible still? It also moves down the javascript and does not place the text on "top" of the js.

Comment: Perhaps one of your styles are making it invisible? Can't really tell without seeing other parts of your code.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "does not place the text on "top" of the js" ? Do you want the particle to be in background? and the text layer on top of it?

Comment: I imagine so. Thanks for the help! Yeah basically the particle was the entire page until I placed the `<h1>` in my HTML. Now, the `<h1>` is at the very top with a huge white bar and has moved the particle down. I want the particle as my total background without it ever moving and everything is on 'top' of it where you can see it. does that make sense?

Comment: I have figured it out, I added `z-index: 0;` to my CSS for `id="particle-canvas"` and then for the stuff I want on 'top', I added `z-index: 1;`. It's formally called layers I believe. Thanks for the help @Nimeshka Srimal for the location of my selector :)